# Mutex на уровне ОС и mutex на уровне Golang

Tags: linux, golang, mutex

В любой многопоточной ОС есть реализация примитивов синхронизации, например в Linux есть Mutex, но в тоже время в Golang тоже есть реализация mutex, я не совсем понимаю как они связаны и связаны ли вообще ?

Comment: ну смотрите, операционная система не знает о том, что есть горутины. Поэтому, мютекс го дожны знать эту кухню. А когда возникает вопрос о настоящей междупоточной синхронизации, то внутри уже можно и мютекс от ОС позвать

Comment: Mutex go занимается горутинами, реализация которых встроена в ЯП - с этим понятно, на счет второго утверждения не совсем понял, то есть go в ситуациях, когда нужно синхронизировать треды дергает api OC для использования Mutex ОС  ?

Comment: горутины могут работь не только в пределах одного потока, но и в нескольких в паралель. И в этом случае может понадобиться позвать обычный мютекс.

Comment: Если вам нужно синхронизировать задачи внутри одного процесса Go, пользуйтесь родным Go мутексом. Он знает о горутинах, многопоточности, сборке мусора, оптимизирован по скорости доступа. Системный мутекс гораздо тяжеловеснее, плюс в случае одноядерного исполнения вы можете попасть в дедлок на системном мутексе.

Системными примитивами синхронизации стоит пользоваться только для синхронизации между процессами. В Windows именованные мутексы могут блокировать потоки, принадлежащие разным процессам. В Linux для этого можно пользоваться файловыми блокировками или именноваными каналами (pipes).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, есть ли у вас какие-либо примеры кода, где в программе на го используется системный mutex (это через cgo происходит ?)